# Arduino Uno - C Code to count from 1-9 and back with button control and 7-Segment display

Tags: c, arduino

I want a code that lets me make my numbers go from 1 to 9 when I press one button, and then go from 9 to 1 when I press the other button.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    // set pin numbers:

    int pinButton = 2;
    int pinButton2 = 3;

    struct number {
     int pinA = 4;
     int pinB = 5;
     int pinC = 6;
     int pinD = 7;
     int pinE = 8;
     int pinF = 9;
     int pinG = 10; 
      };

    int LED = 13;
    int stateLED = LOW;
    int stateButton = 0;
    int stateButton2 = 0;

    number n;

    void setup() {
      pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
      pinMode(pinButton2, INPUT);
      pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(n.pinA, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinB, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinC, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinD, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinE, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinF, OUTPUT);     
      pinMode(n.pinG, OUTPUT);     
    }


    void loop() {
      stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton);  
      stateButton2 = digitalRead(pinButton2);  

      if(stateButton == 0 && stateButton2 == 1) 
      {
          stateLED = HIGH;
          digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);  
   //1    
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, LOW);   

        }

      if(stateButton == 1 && stateButton2 == 0) {
          stateLED = LOW;  
         digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    //2
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, HIGH);   

        }
    }
```

It works from 1 to 2, and I have the rest of the code that go from 3-9 here:

```
{
//3
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   


  //4
  digitalWrite(pinA, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   


  //5
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   

  //6
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   

  //7
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, LOW);   

  //8
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   


  //9
  digitalWrite(pinA, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinB, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinC, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinD, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinE, LOW);   
  digitalWrite(pinF, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(pinG, HIGH);   
}
```

...but the numbers seem to overlap when I combine it to my first code block above and I upload it on the display (ie, I do the following...).

```
    void loop() {
      stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton);  
      stateButton2 = digitalRead(pinButton2);  

      if(stateButton == 0 && stateButton2 == 1) 
      {
          stateLED = HIGH;
          digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);  
   //1    
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, LOW);   
    //2
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, HIGH);       
        }

      if(stateButton == 1 && stateButton2 == 0) {
          stateLED = LOW;  
         digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    //2
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, HIGH);   
   //1    
      digitalWrite(n.pinA, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinB, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinC, HIGH);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinD, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinE, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinF, LOW);   
      digitalWrite(n.pinG, LOW);   
        }
    }
```

Anyone got a better approach?

Comment: "I KNOW Arduino is not C" – then you are mistaken, Arduino code **is** C (and sometimes C++) code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Well if I'm mistaken, then so is Olaf, who rudely said in his comment which I quote "Arduino is not C". Thank you.
And good to know it also uses C++.

Comment: You should learn something about [debouncing](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/debouncing). Take a look at [this is Arduino code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce). BTW what @RishikeshRaje answered you is mandatory: you have to put delays between digits or better, use a timer to increment a variable and a function that display the passed digit.

Comment: Use a const array to store the different 7-seg display sequences. And you need to implement debouncing indeed.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Arduino code is not C! It is compiled as C++, but with additional library files. The code itself cannot be build without them to a runnable program.

Comment: @Olaf So if you use libraries, that changes the language? Interesting… **any** code that uses libraries cannot be compiled/linked without those dependencies. That doesn't make a certain code base suddenly qualify as a separate language… When you write "Arduino code uses external libraries", try and substitute some other C++ project in the place of "Arduino". For example, "<My game written in C++> uses external libraries". Does that mean that your game is not C++?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: The C standard as well as C++ require some behaviour for programm startup and a specific syntax and semantics. However, I'd accept iot is mostly C++, but definitvely not C! Arduino uses a C++ compiler, which is a different language with partly similar or even identical syntax, but possibly different behaviour (e.g. `const` qualifier, overloaded operators, etc. Please see their website.

Comment: @Olaf I am aware that C and C++ are different languages. If the Arduino libraries are designed to work with C++, then yes, it's C++ and not C. Still not a different/custom language, though.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: It very well is, as it adds features which are required. Anyway, I'm not in the mood to tutor.

Comment: @Olaf "It very well is, as it adds features which are required." – um… what? What kind of core language features does it add? It merely adds libraries… that's… absolutely not a different language. Just look at the compiler invocation of the Arduino IDE. It's using a general-purpose C++ compiler, g++, from the avr-gcc toolchain, without any extra clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a delay between the two digits. This can be done by having
a simple software delay in between the two digits.

```
     if(stateButton == 0 && stateButton2 == 1) 
     {
        stateLED = HIGH;
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); 

        // Write digit 1
        delay(50);
        // Write digit 2
        delay(50);
     }
```

The above approach has the property that once you press the button, it will cycle from 1-9 or from 9-1, without stopping.

Comment: Already tried that approach. I prefer the cycle to happen only by the button push, not automatically.

Comment: The cycle will happen by the button push in this method.  You have to take care of debouncing as mentioned by others for it to work in a physical environment.